# ipn not returning VERIFIED or INVALiD

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using Michas ipn script and I am receiving VERIFIED from PayPal and OK 200 but this part of the script is where it seems to stop. I added //notations

```
    if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
    else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data); 
    if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) { 
        throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
    } 
    throw new Exception("status ".$this->response_status);//returns status 200
    throw new Exception("status ".$this->response);//see below
    if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) { 
        return true; throw new Exception("Verified");//nothing returned
    } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) { 
        return false;  throw new Exception("Invalid");//nothing returned

    } else {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
    }
```

below here is what is returned by paypal by using throw new Exception("status ".$this->response);

```
    [19-Oct-2015 14:59:53 UTC] HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Server: Apache
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Paypal-Debug-Id: fdea911830b4f
    Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    DC: slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com
    Date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 14:59:47 GMT
    Content-Length: 8
    Connection: close
    Set-Cookie: cwrClyrK4LoCV1fydGbAxiNL6iG=xW6oYJfS6eHsqsgzQsbhMbE7-VbWj_1d-cNcQrxwKKa-56EbhXpjNMeHUi8wgEe_5J_Dtv9ksoVEE-fvmRQgjZzNrt6UX4Vc-vnhF4q-ymaA7GTWHgypoE-4nnN4eGGmxT8ekVletsOzZuSkcpr2uCuZ_o_2qe4gZnucegLPdnP1H6wLCQSh9vAeMUUlKG_TO92-4NA_LvcAtk83p7uwjzB7L8U1c2vvLivfiS-g3j6oKowAWAhOYtwLlLEVvnpXoWAOyGtPZJNbLDF_hub-VCdh9PA_4UhvMQYJyHv3nSzqvDwqhklL1fk87t3lLzyizpPkZweG6mi-iQyBk4PgS_merjRIESmqD0uNeJL_EIqAkBEZilxWwHmMKskh07SYx146nytFFfAKk8kFQ58_uZ6mxeX9EyBPsUg6z2xMC8OrTyPDqaWH8038mUW;
    domain=.paypal.com; 
    path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Thu, 16-Oct-2025 14:59:47 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/;     Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Wed, 18-Oct-2017 14:59:47 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: Apache=10.74.8.134.1445266787217963; path=/; expires=Wed, 11-Oct-45 14:59:47 GMT
    Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE6.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dappdispatcher%26TIME%3D1661281622; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
    Set-Cookie: Apache=10.74.8.69.1445266787199279; path=/; expires=Wed, 11-Oct-45 14:59:47 GMT
    Set-Cookie: AKDC=slc-b-origin-www-2.paypal.com; expires=Mon, 19-Oct-2015 15:29:47 GMT; path=/; secure
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000

    VERIFIED
```

I am not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was PayPal's adherence to SHA-256. I found this script by Wade Schuler that is forked from the original Micah Carrick IPN, here is the link https://github.com/WadeShuler/PHP-PayPal-IPN To get it to work add this G5 crt located https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/ua-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624 The one included will throw a handshake error. I hope this helps you too!